# @DomainEvent publishes event even in case of rollback

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#core.domain-events

The domainEvent is published whenever repository.save() is called using @DomainEvent annotated method in aggregateRoot(entity).
.
There is a requirement that event is not raised in case of rollback of the transactional method i.e. the method defined by @DomainEvent is called only in case of commit is done not on repository.save() immediately

How this can be achieved?

code

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Invoices implements Serializable {

    private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String invoiceId;

    private String purchaseOrderId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InvoiceStatus status;

    private String invoiceUrl;

    private String merchantName;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    private Timestamp invoiceDate;

    @DomainEvents
    void domainEvent()
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = null;
        try {
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }

}

//Transactional service Method
   @Transactional
    public void createInvoice(InvoiceDTO invoiceDTO) {
        Invoices invoice = buildInvoicesEntity(invoiceDTO);
        //this is duplicate should result in rollback
        Invoices invoice2 = buildInvoicesEntity(invoiceDTO);
        invoicesRepository.save(invoice);
        invoicesRepository.save(invoice2);
    }
```

For obvious reason the above code does a rollback and no row inserted. But the domainEvent() method is called twice.

Is there a way where domainEvent is called only when commit is done, not on rollback.

Comment: Could you add some code please ? I presume that your method is not `@Transactional`. Only your repo is `@Transactional`.

Comment: Added the code, the service method is @Transactional.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this, or figure it out?